# Как на чистом JS добавить контент на страницу.

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, localstorage, content

Всем привет.
Друзья подскажите пожалуйста метод на js как добавлять контент на страницу?
У меня есть перечень товаров (книг). Как на стороне клиента добавить на сайт определенный контент (например картинку с описанием).

Можно ли сделать это через localstorage?

```css
.catalog {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 40px 0;

}
.product {
    width: 202px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}
.product img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.product h6 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.product h6 a {
    color: #000;
}
.product h6 a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
.product h6 span {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.product p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.product p strong { font-weight: bold;}

.item-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.foot-price {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.price {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.price.old {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.price-new {
    color: #fff;
    background: #cc3333;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.add-cart {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #1e1e20;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.add-cart:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap-rate {
    width: 85px; 
    height: 15px;
    background: url(../images/star.png) repeat-x;
    
}
.rate {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/star1.png) repeat-x;
}
```

```html
        <button>Добавить свой товар</button>


<div class="catalog">
            <div class="product item-1">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p> 
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product item-2">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p> 
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="product item-3">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p>  
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product item-4">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p>  
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product item-5">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p>  
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="product item-6">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p>  
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.button {
  width:80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(#161616, .1);
  }

.button.-flower {
  color: #FE8CDF;
  background: #353866;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>JavaScript can Change HTML</h2>

<div id="content">Hello World!</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg' width='64' height='64'><br>text text  text<br><a href='#'><div class='button -flower'>Add to cart</div></a>";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы наверно сделал так. https://jsbin.com/zefirixupu/1/edit?html,js,output

html:

```
<button id="addItem">Добавить свой товар</button>
<div class="catalog">
            <div class="product item-1">
                <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
                <div class="item-footer">
                    <div class="wrap-rate">
                        <div class="rate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p> 
                    <div class="foot-price">
                        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('addItem');
var catalog = document.querySelector('.catalog');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var productsLength = document.querySelectorAll('.product').length;
  var html = '<div class="product item-'+(productsLength+1)+'">'
                +'<a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>'
                +'<div class="item-footer">'
                    +'<div class="wrap-rate">'
                        +'<div class="rate"></div>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p>'
                    +'<div class="foot-price">'
                        +'<a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
            +'</div>';
  catalog.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});
```

Но по идее лучше конечно использовать хотя бы какой-нибудь простенький шаблонизатор. Например тот, который предлагает библиотека underscorejs.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант с использованием шаблонизатора. https://jsbin.com/jipekigejo/3/edit?html,js,output

html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script id="itemTemplate" type="x-template/underscore">
    <div class="product item-<%=number%>">
    <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
    <div class="item-footer">
      <div class="wrap-rate">
        <div class="rate"></div>
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p> 
      <div class="foot-price">
        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>  

<button id="addItem">Добавить свой товар</button>
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="product item-1">
    <a href=""><img src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/hpsorcstone.jpg?w=405" alt=""></a>
    <div class="item-footer">
      <div class="wrap-rate">
        <div class="rate"></div>
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Sort</a> <span>by Year</span></p> 
      <div class="foot-price">
        <a class="add-cart" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('addItem');
var itemTemplate = document.getElementById('itemTemplate').innerText;
var catalog = document.querySelector('.catalog');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var productsLength = document.querySelectorAll('.product').length;

  var html = _.template(itemTemplate)({number: productsLength+1});
  catalog.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});
```